# spring boot com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, spring-boot

i start a new maven project with spring-boot and jersey. I got an error when i called: mvn clean spring-boot:run.

A part of my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
```

Any ideas?
Thank

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing the jersey-server libraries. Pls include following :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i don't new this dependency. I had a WebContent-folder with the web.xml. I removed it and it works fine now.

Comment: Nope! Unfortunatelly this is not the root cause, at least at my enviroment it did not solve the problem. I am still struggling with this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Exactly so the baseline is that this jar was not getting resolved in the classpath either due to mismatch of libraries in pom or absence of this jar totally and hence throwing this error out. When u restored your repo the app was able to find this jar and so no error was thrown out.

Answer (score 0):

*A little bit old the question, but... anyway I leave a comment regarding my experience with this problem.*

In my case, I solve this problem **cleaning the local `~/.m2/repository`**, letting the maven (while re-building the EurekaServer) get the dependencies (properly this time). After that, without even touch my pom.xml, the server started working well. I supposed that at my previous maven local repository, got something that were "disturbing" the spring-boot dependencies (as our maven repos used to be full of tons of dependencies, resulting of the several proof-of-concepts ran).